# How to fetch the data form SQL Server into the Visual force Page in salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, community, sqlserver

I want to fetch the data from sql server into salesforce visual force page.Is there any specific approach for this?Please help me with this.

Comment: You can't execute SQL in Apex in native. Apex support SOQL. Approach is the integration with SQL which is a different and complex thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I've no personal experience of this, but Salesforce's [External Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=external_object_define.htm) mechanism is one approach. This allows an external table to be accessed in your org via largely the same SOQL API that your internal Salesforce objects (tables) are accessed by. I believe at present the access is read-only.

From a quick Google here is a blog post on the subject [Creating a Salesforce External Data Source using an OData Service Created in .Net](http://blog.giovannimodica.com/post/creating-a-salesforce-external-data-source-using-an-odata-service-created-in-net) from [Giovanni's Blog](http://blog.giovannimodica.com/).